# .NET & Entity Framework : query database by using IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have a method which takes an `IQueryable<TEntity>` where all my filters have been applied and now I want to query the database by using this IQueryable

The IQueryable i defined like:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
```

and then you can for example :

```
query.Where(q => q.Parameter == true)
```

and then it should transfer the empty collection to the repository where it should query the database

Code:

```
protected EntityDBContext _context;
protected DbSet<TEntity> _set;

public async Task<List<TEntity>> ReadAsync(IQueryable<TEntity> queryable) 
{
    // something like this but by using the dbset
    return queryable.ToList();
}
```

Or should I just merge all the filters and then query the database?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. If `queryable` already has all of the filters applied, then you just need to call `ToList` (or `await .... ToListAsync()`) on it.

Comment: but does it query the database?

Comment: Have you check the EF tutorials and "Getting Started" examples? This is foundational information - as in you can't use EF at all if you don't understand how queries work. You can't just copy "best practices" without understanding what you're doing. I suspect you're trying to use the "repository" *anti*pattern to "abstract" higher level classes. A DbSet is already a single-entity repository, a DbContext is already a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. Why would any class reference a single DbSet ?

Comment: but why should the IQueryable which has no connection to the dbset or db context. i have i IQueryable like 
`IQueryable<TEntity> filter = Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsQueryable();`
and then `filter.Where(x => true)`. After this I give the queryable to a method where it should convert to the sql statement

Comment: Read the docs and examples first. The very comment `but by using the dbset` means you misunderstand how EF Core works. DbSet is the repository. It's queried using LINQ, which only works through IQueryable. `DbSet` implements `IQueryable` so you can *already* query any entity any way you want. Unless you break it by trying to put lower-level abstractions over DbSet

Comment: `IQueryable<TEntity> filter = Enumerable.Empty<TEntity>().AsQueryable();` that's a bug. That's not a filter. That's an empty list cast to its query interface. You can query that empty list, but the result will always be empty. When you try to use `filter` you are only using that empty list.

Comment: so i should not insert the query in a new querable. Instead I should merge all the fitlers that are applied to the queriable and after this pass it to the dbset and query it there?

Comment: yeah i want the filter from the empty list to transfer to the list (dbset) which queries the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic filters using **Func** delegates like this

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithCondition(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
        {
            return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression);
        }
```

You can call this method like this. It will accept multiple conditions as well.

```
public List<EntityNameModel> GetList(bool parameter)
        {
            return GetWithCondition(x => x.Parameter == true).ToList();
            
        }
```

This will basically return the list of records. If you don't want to pass any condition then it will return whole list of entity records.

Comment: but in my case the expression are "stored" in a different iqueryable